# stock exchange with API (bitfinex) and a phone

Tags: android, node.js, rest

I have a little experience in developing, so could you help me by showing the general idea.
There is a stock exchange with API (bitfinex).

1) So I need to monitor some data with as little delay as possible. I don't need to do any "heavy" calculations.

2) A sound signal on a mobile phone (Android os) should ring when the certain event occurs.

I think, charts can take a large amount of data (one chart is 1 month long in 1 minute increments, and there're may be 10 charts  and maybe more). May be I need to build on  few more charts according to a certain algorithm (e.g. draw a moving average over a certain period of time, find extremums, and draw a graph based on them).

I think that I can process the data from the stock on a server and then using the API,  if necessary send some parameters to a phone.
Do I have to use a  server or just a phone can  handle this task?
Thank you in advance for your help!